# variable 'fstream grabpass' has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error reading from a file using fstream, on line 37 (fstream grabpass("passwords.txt");) but doesn't seem like I'm doing anything wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int i,passcount,asterisks;
char replace, value, newchar;
string username,password,storedUsername,storedPassword;

int login(string username, string password)
{
    if (username=="test"/*storedUsername*/)
    {
        if (password==storedPassword)
        cout<<"Win!";
        else
        cout<<"Username correct, password incorrect.";
    }
    else cout<<"Lose. Wrong username and password.";
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Username: ";
    cin>>username;
    cout<<"Password: ";
    do
    {
    newchar = getch();
    if (newchar==13)break;
    for (passcount>0;asterisks==passcount;asterisks++)cout<<"*";
    password = password + newchar;
    passcount++;
    } while (passcount!=10);

    fstream grabpass("passwords.txt");
    getline(grabpass,storedPassword);
    grabpass.close();
    login(username,password);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add `#include <fstream>`. At a guess, `<iostream>` is probably including a declaration of `fstream` (most like via `<iosfwd>`), but not a definition, so it has incomplete type when you try to define an object of that type.

Comment: Erm. Why didn't I already do that...thanks, Jerry. A stupid blunder on my part.